# Kafka producer - multiple connections to broker vs single global connection

Tags: asp.net-web-api, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using confluent C# client for connecting with Kafka and trying to create an API that could be used by multiple existing applications to push messages in a topic.

Now I am unsure if I should simply create new connection every time I get a hit on API or create a global singleton connection that could be reused every-time. Second approach sounds better to me as creating connection on each hit could be time consuming but it could also lead to issues like hogging a connection permanently and issue in handling global connection which might be terminated by Kafka broker.

Below is skeleton of what I initially thought of going with:

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    IProducer<string, string> producer = null;
    public SampleController()
    {
        producer = GetSingletonInstance();
    }

    public async void Post(ProducerRequest request)
    {
        var deliveryReport = await producer.ProduceAsync(request.Topic, new Message<string, string> { Key = request.Key, Value = request.Value });
    }
```

Please suggest some of the things that I should consider if I go with global connection approach

Comment: Kafka can be visualized as a giant buffer between producers and consumers. You can have N producers pushing data to a broker.

Comment: Producers are typically shared over the entire life cycle of one application